# How to run CFSocket on a background thread for more accurate ping time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, sockets

Background...

I am modifying Apple’s [SimplePing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html) example to do an ICMP ping for an iPhone app.  The code wraps a native socket in a CFSocket object specifying a read callback, then adds it as a run loop source on the main thread.  When a packet is sent to the socket, the callback is invoked to time the round trip, verify the contents, update the UI, etc.

Question...

What would be the best approach for moving this processing to a background thread so the ping time is as accurate as possible?  I need to measure the precise time between the call to the socket “sendto” method and the callback invocation without interruption.

Any examples or pseudo code would be extremely helpful.  I have done a lot of reading on threading in Cocoa (NSThread vs. NSOperation, NSRunLoop, etc.), but so far, I can’t quite piece it all together.

Thanks

Comment: According to [this post](http://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2009/Feb/msg00047.html) there’s already a lot happening under the `CFSocket` hood threading-wise. Might be useful reading for you.

Comment: Just to clarify... the reason for wanting to do the background processing is that the ping times for the original code (running on the main thread's CFRunLoop) are taking longer than expected.

Comment: @zoul: Thanks. I have seen that thread, but I'll read back over it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to support iOS 3.x? If not, you could look into using Grand Central Dispatch; in this scenario, you would specify the socket as a source for a dispatch queue and give it the highest priority.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need to support iOS 3.x so GCD is not an option.  Here is what I am trying now:  I am using NSThread's detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject: method to invoke my existing method that sets up the CFSocket as a source on the CFRunLoop (which would now be the run loop of the new thread).  Am I on the right track?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, is there any code samples ?